# Youtube API queries: starts-before,starts-after,ends-before,ends-after

Tags: xml, api, youtube, feed, gdata

I am building a video search-engine of a different variety to youtube.

I am struggling to make any of the above queries yield results. My syntax is typically as follows:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?&author=user&ends-before=2009

Does anyone have any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starts-before, starts-after, ends-before and ends-after parameters can only be used when retrieving live events:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_retrieving_live_events.html

Also, their values must be specified in ISO8601 format, e.g. 2009-01-01.
Excluding that, your query looks correct.
Try this sample:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=GoogleDevelopers